# firebase emulator with real devices

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, flutter

I am building a react-native app. And I want to test my code on real devices.
Has anybody tried the firebase emulator with real iphone/android devices?
In my case,Firebase emulator worked fine with the Android emulator/Iphone simulator but not with real devices. I am getting the following error.

Error [Error: [auth/network-request-failed] A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 15):

Finally, I am able to run firebase emulator with real devices.
Thats how firebase.json looks like. I added the "host":"192.168.1.114". 192.168.1.114 is the IP assigned to your computer by router.

```
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host":"192.168.1.114",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host":"192.168.1.114",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host":"192.168.1.114",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

After changing the firebase.json. I added the following lines for auth and firestore respectively.

```
auth().useEmulator("http://192.168.1.114:9099");
firestore().settings({ host: "192.168.1.114:8080", ssl: false });
```

After these changes, I was able to push data to the firebase emulator  from real devices. Your computer and devices should be connected with the same network.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but my android device still can't access the emulators.  Is there anything else that I need to try.  Please help.  Here is what I tried:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437787/firebase-emulators-with-flutter-app-on-real-android-device/68438424#68438424

Comment: I have tried this on iPhone and it just doesn't work. Here is my SO question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166716/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-emulator-with-ios-device

Comment: This is not ideal, though. What if the IP address changes frequently? I wonder if there's a way for this to work with dynamic IP

Comment: Did you get it working with api v9 (modular)?

Answer (score 2):

Using flutter on a macbook, this is what worked for me:

```
...
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
...
```

then in my flutter app:

```
// the ip to my computer
const localHostString = '192.168.1.81';
await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(localHostString, 9099);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator(localHostString, 8080);
```