# firebase emulators with flutter app on real android device

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-tools

I have flutter application running on real android device.  I am using auth, firestore, storage, cloud functions.  I am trying to use firebase emulators but with no luck.  Here are things I tried:

In my main function in Flutter I am calling this function:

```
Future<void> useEmulators() async {
  // this is the ip of my mac on the router
  final ip = "192.168.1.133";
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(ip, 9099);
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator(ip, 9199);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator(ip, 8080, sslEnabled: false);
  FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-east4')
       .useFunctionsEmulator(ip, 5001);
}
```

I am calling this function from my main() like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // this is where the function is called
  await useEmulators();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preloadSVGs();
  final hiveDbService = HivedbService();
  await hiveDbService.init();
  return runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      // observers: [Logger()],
      overrides: [
        sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(sharedPreferences),
        hiveDbServiceProvider.overrideWithValue(hiveDbService),
      ],
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then I updated firebase.json like this:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
    "source": "functions",
    "runtime": "nodejs12"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "192.168.1.133",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "192.168.1.133",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "192.168.1.133",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "host": "192.168.1.133",
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "192.168.1.133",
      "port": 9199
    }
  }
}
```

I updated AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    </application>
```

I ran the emulators like this:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

When I try to sign up, nothing happens.
I expect that a new auth record or document to be created but nothing happens.  The app keep waiting for a while and it times out.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to access firebase emulator from my android device.  What a relief.  I had two problems.

I fixed the ip addresses inside my firestore.json like this:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
    "source": "functions",
    "runtime": "nodejs12"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9199
    }
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "public",
      "public": "web",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
    },
    {
      "target": "admin",
      "public": "admin",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The other problem I had was that I was not using wifi.  You must have wifi and both your mobile and emulators should be on the same router.

Finally I am able to test my code on a real device with local firebase.