# Unable to connect to Firebase Emulator with iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect with an iOS device to the Firebase Auth and RealTime Database Emulator.

The thing is, I can connect and use emulator through Firebase Admin using NodeJS on local machine (trough http://localhost:9000?ns=my-project).

Also I am able to connect with an iOS device to the remote Firebase server... But locally it doesn't work. It throws bunch of random errors, like this (when I try to complete registration/authentication):

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
> server."  NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.3:9099/www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=myKeyGoesHere

and

> Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase.core Code=1 "Unable to get latest
> value for query FQuerySpec (path: /news, params: { }), client offline
> with no active listeners and no matching disk cache entries"

Here is firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I changed rules just in case:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

but its not that.

and here is how I try to connect to database in my iOS application(my FirebaseManager class):

```
 init(){
      Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"192.168.1.3", port:9099)
 }

  private lazy var newsNodeRef:DatabaseReference? = {
    
    guard let urlString = getBaseURL() else {return nil}
    
    let node = LocalConstants.kNewsRef // this has value of 'news'
    return Database.database(url: urlString).reference(withPath: node)
}()


    
    private func getBaseURL()->String?{
        let environment = Environment()
        guard let connectionProtocol = environment.configuration(PlistKey.firebaseConnectionProtocol), let baseURL = environment.configuration(PlistKey.firebaseDatabaseURL) else {return nil}
        let urlString = "\(connectionProtocol)://\(baseURL)"
        
        return urlString // this produces something like 'http://192.168.1.3:9000?ns=my-project' (its fetched from Configuration Settings file based on selected environment)
    }
```

the thing is, the exact same setup works on remote server, if I just change the environment(which automatically changes base url).

I have also allowed insecure http loads in info.plist, just to be sure if it is not that, but still doesn't work.

This is what I get in console when I run emulators:

[image: terminal]

What is the problem here?

Comment: I think there are bugs in firebase emulator.

I think you haven't missed details such as your device and computer being connected to the same wi-fi network.

I did some trials and got the following results.
The emulator does not work for Firebase auth and storage for iOS 12 and earlier. Firestore is working.
I haven't tried iOS 13 but it works perfectly on current iOS version.
You will see that you get the same error when you try it with iOS 12 in the Xcode simulator.

Comment: Yeah, I am connected on the same Wifi as my Mac...  When it comes to iOS, I am on latest version at the moment of speaking, 15.3.1 @İsaDiliballı In my case, iPhone simulator works normally with Firebase Emulator.

Comment: There are many people who have this problem. I had the same problem. My conclusion is that the emulator does not work on the real device.
There was a question and answer about this problem, I couldn't find the link. Google employees had the answer in it, the problem was in the way that it will be fixed.

Comment: @İsaDiliballı Actually I got it work. But also I discovered a quite big issue with whole thing related to Local Network Access prompt. You can check Dev Portal link in my answer for more details if interested.

Answer (score 8):

I replied a little late .
I saw the solution you found. It didn't work for me but I'm sure it has worked for a lot of people.

I found a solution too.
Actually, I couldn't see a problem for iOS 15. My problem was that it didn't work on iOS 14 and earlier.

Solution;

First, you need the MacBook's IP address.
To find the IP address;
You can access it right under System preferences -> Network -> Status.

Then we need to make some changes in the firebase.json file.

Adding “host” : “IP” for each part.
Overwrite the “host” part with the “port” part.

```
"emulators": {
"auth": {
  "host": "192.168.1.11”,
  "port": 9100
},
"functions": {
  "host": "192.168.1.11”,
  "port": 5002
},
"firestore": {
  "host": "192.168.1.11”,
  "port": 8081
},
"database": {
  "host": "192.168.1.11",
  "port": 9001
},
"storage": {
  "host": "192.168.1.11",
  "port": 9200
},
"ui": {
  "enabled": true
}
```

Then we need to add in swift codes.
We need to write the IP address in the host part.
More precisely, we will replace the parts that say localhost with the IP address.

```
let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
settings.host = "192.168.1.11:8081"
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
settings.isSSLEnabled = false
Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
    
Storage.storage().useEmulator(withHost:"192.168.1.11", port:9200)
Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"192.168.1.11", port:9100)
let db = Database.database(url:"http://192.168.1.11:9001?ns=firebaseappname")
Functions.functions().useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://192.168.1.11:5002")
```

I think this solution will work in JS, android and other languages.

I would appreciate it if you tried this solution and let me know if it works.
It worked for me.

Comment: This should be the correct way. The iOS device needs to be able to connect to the emulator via the network using the host's IP, usually 192.168.x.y, not localhost or 127.0.0.1. If the command firebase emulators:start prints 127.0.0.1:xxxx or localhost:xxxx as Host:Port, the host needs to be set to the IP 192.168.x.y. in the firebase.json. You can check whether it's working from your iOS device's browser opeining 192.168.x.y:<port> where <port> is one of the emulated firebase services.  Additionally, incoming request could be blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Thank you, setting local IP address "192.168.*.*" and "isSSLEnabled = false" was helpful! Later, I found that if in "firebase.json" you set "host": "0.0.0.0”, it will also work. Server Firebase version 12.4.6, client 10.12.0.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved it. The solution/problem, I don't even know how to declare it, was with `Local Network Access prompt & permissions` and its buggy behaviour (as well how I was trying to access my Mac by ip).

At first I didn't even see a prompt shows every time, but I guess it was related to a wrong setup of a `port`, `host` etc.

But when I correctly set local computer's ip and reverted `firebase.json` to it's default settings (which is what worked for me), the prompt started to jump out every time.

The thing is, prompt's behaviour seems broken, because instead of jumping before you try to access devices in a local network, it pops out after that action is made. Quite fast, but still after `Auth` system responded, which doesn't make sense.

Here, it can be confusing, cause error that is returned from a Firebase Auth system in the case when you didn't allow `Local Network Access` usage, doesn't really tell you much about real cause. See my ( [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166716/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-emulator-with-ios-device)) above to see the errors.

After that terrible flow, I allowed access trough the prompt. Once I did that, on every next 'api' call towards `Emulator` was successful. Worked like a charm.

The real problem here is `Local Network Access prompt`. Cause we don't have at all control over it, so we can't that easily trigger it, or easily get info what user have selected/chosen at the moment / or before. It's triggered by the system in certain conditions.

Luckily this is just for development :) but I hope it will be fixed/improved soon, cause it should.

I found a lot about this topic and its considered as a bug [Local Network Access Prompt problems](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663858) on Dev portal:

Answer (score -1):

I was also faced the same problem while using the firebase auth in iOS simulator
then i change my code little bit

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I have made a check for only android and it works for me
Inside this method you can see it only works for android.