# Cannot connect to Firestore Local Emulator from Swift UI App Simulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-tools

IP_ADDRESS = 127.0.0.1 and also my "192.168..." IP address per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166716/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-emulator-with-ios-device), which I've tried their solutions too but with no avail.
Here is the code I'm using to connect to all the emulators:

```swift
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            
            Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: IP_ADDRESS, port: 9099)
            
            let storeSettings = Firestore.firestore().settings
            storeSettings.host = IP_ADDRESS+":8080"
            storeSettings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
            storeSettings.isSSLEnabled = false
            Firestore.firestore().settings = storeSettings
            
            FirebaseStorage.Storage.storage().useEmulator(withHost: IP_ADDRESS, port: 9199)
            
            FirebaseFunctions.Functions.functions().useEmulator(withHost: IP_ADDRESS, port: 5001)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            }
            
            return true
        }
    }
```

I get these errors:

```
error when getting profile: Optional(Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=14 "Failed to get document because the client is offline." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get document because the client is offline.})

2023-07-19 18:13:44.586226-0400 Pronto[25712:2998528] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (7fadc150eba8) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'

2023-07-19 18:13:44.587878-0400 Pronto[25712:2998528] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

 This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

2023-07-19 18:13:44.592171-0400 Pronto[25712:2998536] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (7fadc150eba8) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'
```

The first error relates to me trying to check if a document exists in the firestore. However, since it can't even connect to the emulator, I'd like to deal with that first.

I've checked the obvious things such as making sure all the ports and ip match. The emulators seem to start fine.

Here's a screenshot - you can see its using my 192.168.x.y address because I manually changed it in the firebase.json file. However, I originally had left everything AS IS, in their defaults.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I swear it's bug, after bug, after bug with these technologies (SwiftUI and Xcode mainly). I hoping this is not another one.

Edit:
Current code

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // I've tried with both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1", the "128.0.0.1" error is above the "localhost" errors are below.
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: "localhost", port: 9099)
        
        let storeSettings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        storeSettings.host = "localhost:8080"
        storeSettings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        storeSettings.isSSLEnabled = false
        Firestore.firestore().settings = storeSettings
        
        FirebaseStorage.Storage.storage().useEmulator(withHost: "127.0.0.1", port: 9199)
        
        FirebaseFunctions.Functions.functions().useEmulator(withHost: "127.0.0.1", port: 5001)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": []
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

errors:

```
2023-07-19 20:29:57.524333-0400 Pronto[32513:3147732] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

error when getting profile: Optional(Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=14 "Failed to get document because the client is offline." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get document because the client is offline.})

2023-07-19 20:29:57.575475-0400 Pronto[32513:3147727] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

2023-07-19 20:29:57.612341-0400 Pronto[32513:3147732] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

2023-07-19 20:30:00.147268-0400 Pronto[32513:3147733] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (7f8fd1a0a638) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'

2023-07-19 20:30:00.599262-0400 Pronto[32513:3147733] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

 This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
2023-07-19 20:30:00.894489-0400 Pronto[32513:3147733] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (7f8fd1a0a638) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'
```

Comment: `Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: "localhost", port: 9099)` typically does the trick. What does your `firebase.json` file look like?

Comment: I've edited my post with the code I'm currently using and the firebase.json. I get: 2023-07-19 20:29:57.524333-0400 Pronto[32513:3147732] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]   if I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Note Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server. Have you done that?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Unfortunately, I have done that, and the error persisted.